# point for list item in listbox asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, listboxitem

I am using an ASP ListBox in my asp.net page. I obviously add items to this control. I have customised individual background colours of the listitems. I also want to change the Cursor to a pointer when the User hovers over it. I am struggling to achieve this.  Is there a QUICK way to do this at all?  I do not want to use the HTML control version of this.  It has to be using the ASP.NET list control.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way of doing this is through CSS, like this:

By referencing the single element ID:

```
#YourListBoxID:hover { 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

By making a CSS class:

```
.HoverCursorPointer:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then you would need to apply the CSS class to your ASP.NET ListBox, like this:

```
<asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" runat="server" CssClass="HoverCursorPointer">

</asp:ListBox>
```

Just for reference, here is a list of [CSS cursor property values](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

UPDATE:

To apply the hover cursor to each list item as well, then do this:

```
protected void ListBox1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    foreach (ListItem item in lb.Items)
    {
        item.Attributes["class"] = "HoverCursorPointer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  many thanks for your reply.  I did do this originally. The cursor changed when i moved the mouse over the listbox but when i directly hovered over a listitem in it it changed back to its default value.

Comment: See UPDATE in answer.

Comment: hi, thanks again for your time in all this.  I did try using item.Attribute[class] = "mystyle" when adding the listitems in the 1st place. I just tried using this inte _dataBound event but it still does not work :(

Comment: OMG, I completely screwed up the CSS class, because I forgot to include `:hover` with it, see edited answer.